# XText typed literals

Tags: types, xtext

Another XText question. While experimenting with XText, i tried to create a language which is capable of a basic variable declaration, and value assignment. My first try was something like this:

```
Grammar:
    elements+=Element*;

Element:
    Declaration | ValueAssignment;

Declaration:
    type=Type isArray='[]'? name=ID;

enum Type:
    int | string;

ValueAssignment:
    declaration=[Declaration] '=' ???;
```

So a simple example would look like this:

```
int foo
int[] bar
string fooBar

foo = 10
bar = { 10, 20, 30 }
fooBar = "Sample text"
```

**So my questions:**

- If we don't take the array part into consideration
  for now, how could i enforce, that if a `Declaration` has a type of
  `int`, then only such a literal can be on the right hand side of an
  assignment, what matches an integer regex? Same for `string`?
- If we TAKE the array part into consideration, how could that be done?
  Sure i could write a rule, like `ArrayLiteral: {ArrayLiteral}'{' elements+=???* '}';`
  but what would be the type of the elements rule? How could i ensure the type there?

I went through the XText guides, but anywhere, where types came into play, it used XBase elements which were very confusing. Any help, or pointers on where to start would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I managed to perform basic type checking on this simple example, however I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution:

The slightly modified grammar:

```
Grammar:
    elements+=Element*;

Element:
    Declaration | ValueAssignment;

Declaration:
    type=Type isArray?='[]'? name=ID;

enum Type:
    int | string;

ValueAssignment:
    declaration=[Declaration] '=' value=Literal;

IntLiteral:
    value=INT;

StringLiteral:
    value=STRING;

PrimitiveLiteral:
    IntLiteral | StringLiteral;

ArrayLiteral:
    {ArrayLiteral} '{' elements+=PrimitiveLiteral* '}';

Literal:
    PrimitiveLiteral | ArrayLiteral;
```

And a **validator** on top of it (the grammar itself has no constraints on the types):

```
class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator {

    public static val INVALID_TYPE = 'invalidType'

    @Check
    def checkTypeOfValueAssignment(ValueAssignment valAssign) {
        val isArray = valAssign.declaration.isArray
        val type = valAssign.declaration.type
        val literal = valAssign.value
        if (isArray) {
            if (!(literal instanceof ArrayLiteral)) {
                error(
                    "Invalid primitive literal, array required"
                    , MyDslPackage.Literals.VALUE_ASSIGNMENT__VALUE
                    , INVALID_TYPE
                )
                return
            }
            val arrLiteral = literal as ArrayLiteral
            arrLiteral.elements.forEach[l | l.checkType(type) ]
        } else {
            val primLiteral = literal as PrimitiveLiteral
            primLiteral.checkType(type)
        }
    }

    def checkType(PrimitiveLiteral element, Type type) {
        if (type == Type.INT && !(element instanceof IntLiteral)) {
            error(
                "Invalid primitive literal, int required"
                , MyDslPackage.Literals.VALUE_ASSIGNMENT__VALUE
                , INVALID_TYPE
            )
            return
        } 
        if (type == Type.STRING && !(element instanceof StringLiteral)) {
            error(
                "Invalid primitive literal, string required"
                , MyDslPackage.Literals.VALUE_ASSIGNMENT__VALUE
                , INVALID_TYPE
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**My modified question:** Is it OK to do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the grammar you can write the syntax of your language. The semantics of the source code often cannot be implemented with the grammar. For this reason there is the validation class in Xtext projects. It should be used to check the semantics of the source code.

Yes, you solved your problem as provided by Xtext. I don't know if your websearch was that deep, but maybe you have read something about 'Xsemantics' which is an other Eclipse plug-in for implementing a type system for Xtext languages. It has a fancy and hard to understand DSL to write type rules which will then be translated into Java source code and integrated into the type hierarchy of your '...MyDslValidator' class.

Comment: Wow this looks pretty cool, but you were definitely right about the hard-to-understand part :D Since then my google-adventure also led me to Xtext TS (type system), which looks much easier to understand at first, but may lack some features, that Xsemantics has.

Comment: One thing I missed to tell about the Validator class is that you can also implement quick fixes in a very easy way. I have seen, that you already implemented the optional 'INVALID_TYPE' constant. It is an identifier, associated to the error marker, which allows Xtext to determine a quick fix. You should have a look at the '...mydsl.ui.MyDslQuickfixProvider' class (located in the ui project). If you implement a quick fix method there for a special validator constant, the user experiance will increase because then you are able to tell Xtext how it can be corrected automatically.

Comment: That's a feature, never looked into. It's really useful when eclipse suggests something for an error. Will definitely look into Xsemantics, it looks like a really nice way to implement a type system. For any chance, are you a dev of Xsemantics? Or do you know, about how active the development of the framework is? I saw the current last post is October 2014 on their site, so it looks like pretty active, while Xtext/Ts doesn't look like it's not actively in development.

Comment: No, I am not a developer of Xsemantics, but I have met the developer a few times, for example at the XtextCON where he presented Xsemantics. I think it is quite active and will integrate it with new versions of Xtext in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's just what i wanted to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

One small addition about Xsemantics (I'm its author, and it's still actively developed): the syntax of the DSL is meant to mimic the one of formal type systems; so it might be hard to understand if you're not familiar with formal type systems.  I think, however, that a small and basic understanding of formal type systems is required anyway if you plan to implement any non trivial type system.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I have read the whole documentation repeatedly while going to work/home, and I think, that I'm starting to understand whats going on :). I still need to try it out for myself in practice, but the sample projects looked perfect for learning. Thanks for making Xsemantics open source (and so easy to setup), it seems like it's the best tool for making type systems.

Comment: Glad you're enjoying it :)
Please feel free to ask if you have any problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest also writing a type computer class to provide expected and actual types and then using it in your Validator.